# Compilation error Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2.4, setup-upgrade, static-content-deploy, setup-di-compile

what kind of compilation error is this?

Can I share with you other info?

I have Magento 2.4.3
https://ibb.co/sVFd0Nq

Answer (score 0):

your was changed permissions of project?
first change the permissions, second check and share the env.php file in /app/code

Comment: Okay thanks folder are in 755 and i made a link where you can see env.php file https://aarte.com.au/env.txt Let me know if you need other info or log thanks

Comment: when not load the files of composer it possible show is error. please $ composer update

Comment: Ok i updated composer but i have same issue..

Comment: you installed elasticsearch and running in your server? look that in [URL]:9200